# Rails Tutorial Chapter 8.2.3 NoMethodError in Users#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm receiving NoMethodError in Users#new after adding the partial app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
Showing /Users/gjb/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
```

Here's my app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @users.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
        prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    <p>Ther were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's my app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>    
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've spent a lot of time on this trying to get it right but I'm feeling stuck at this point. Any clue will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your partial where you have `<% if @users.errors.any? %>` needs to be `<% if @user.errors.any? %>`. You've got plural instead of singular, so you're using a variable you never set. And instance variables are `nil` the first time they're used instead of raising an error.

Comment: This isn't the first time plural vs singular has gotten me. I should have seen that one. Thanks!

Comment: @Emily, +1 because you've been chosen :)

Answer (score 2):

In `app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb`, replace:

```
<% if @users.errors.any? %>
```

With:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
```

Indeed, `@users` variable doesn't exist.

Comment: doh! Thanks! I really should have caught that one.

Comment: generally when 2 answers are equivalent, one choose the first to have been posted. Well, never mind, keep Emily's (but remember +1 exist :) )

Comment: not sure what to do. Both answers are basically equivalent but Emily adds that "instance variables are `nil` the first time they're used instead of raising an error." I didn't know that and the `nil` caused me some confusion.